# how to monitor my order operation with TWS API

Tags: c#, tws

I create a C# WinForm to monitor my TWS order operation (place order, cancel order and modify order's amount and price). It is easy to monitor place order and cancel order, but when I modify my order in TWS manually (for example on the chart. see the screenshot), there are no messages recieved from TWS about the modification. I want to know how can I get the modification with TWS API?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response data was received by EWrapper.OpenOrders